# progressive download of http links and play in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to download from a  http link progressively and then play it.That is first save some bytes and play it in the meanwhile buffer the next file.
Could you please let me know as how i can achieve that in android?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

With the first answer, If you use RandomAccessFile, you will don't need to create so many files and restart MediaPlayer.
Just download and play, if the file is not enough to play, you can pause the MediaPlayer.